# Simple Calculator using Java scanner and vector classes

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to create a simple calculator that calculates according to precedence. The method is passed a string(expression) that must be solved for. The way I am doing it is first parsing the string into two vectors, one holding the numbers and the other holding the operands. After I have successfully parsed the string, I then calculate and return the answer. I am getting a java.util.InputMismatchException from the scanner class I am using. Here is my code:

```
public static int performCalc(String problem)
{
    // 3 * 2 + 4 / 1 + 2 + 4
    Pattern op = Pattern.compile("[*/+-]"); 
    String prob; 
    Vector<Integer> nums = new Vector();
    Vector<String> operands = new Vector();
    int answer = 0, index = 0, numOne, numTwo; 
    Scanner scNums = new Scanner(problem);
    Scanner scOperands = new Scanner(problem); 
    while(scNums.hasNext()) 
    {
        nums.add(scNums.nextInt());
    }
    while(scNums.hasNext()) 
    {
        operands.add(scNums.next(op));
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<operands.size(); i++)
    {
        if(operands.get(i) == "*" || operands.get(i) == "/")
        {
            nums.set(i, calc(nums.get(i), operands.get(i), nums.get(i+1)));
            nums.remove(i+1);
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<operands.size(); i++)
    {
        if(operands.get(i) == "+" || operands.get(i) == "-")
        {
            nums.set(i, calc(nums.get(i), operands.get(i), nums.get(i+1)));
            nums.remove(i+1);
        }
    }
    return nums.firstElement(); 
}
public static int calc(int numOne, String operand, int numTwo)
{
    if(operand == "*")
        return numOne*numTwo;
    if(operand == "/")
        return numOne/numTwo;
    if(operand == "+")
        return numOne+numTwo;
    if(operand == "-")
        return numOne-numTwo; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Is there a better and more elegant way to parse the string(or to approach the problem)? What am  I doing wrong? The debugger isn't giving much info on the error.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if this is the problem but shouldn't the code of the second while loop be

```
 while(scOperands.hasNext())
```

Answer (score 0):

In first loop

```
while(scNums.hasNext())
```

you are reading data from input parameter (problem) where I suppose you passed string with integers and operands (something like "3 * 2 +"). So when you call nextInt on sign "*" you got InputMismatchException.

Probably you want to write something like this (be careful - what could happen if there is odd number of signs in input parameter):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(problem);
while(scanner.hasNext()) 
{
    nums.add(scanner.nextInt());
    operands.add(scanner.next(op));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use [Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) (RPN). It can be confusing at first, but once you understand the syntax, it is very easy to implement with a stack. Rather than dealing with a Scanner, your input can be as simple as a delimited string. [Here](http://andreinc.net/2011/01/03/rpn-calculator-using-python-scala-and-java/) is an example implementation that I found on the web. Good luck!